# For a hypothetical high-power nuclear spacecraft, where does the waste heat go?

Tags: nuclear

It seems that all nuclear propulsion concepts extract fission energy as heat, and somehow convert a portion of that heat to energy in the desired form, such as electrical (e.g. to power an ion thruster). It always amounts to creating heat in one part of the system and dumping waste heat somewhere else. For example: using a working fluid that is heated, perhaps discharged through a turbine, cooled, and sent back to the heat source. As the turbine (for example) extracts mechanical energy from the working fluid, the equivalent heat energy is removed. Nevertheless, there is still a lot of waste heat to be dissipated somewhere.

My question is: in the higher power concepts, how is all that waste heat removed from the spacecraft? In the vacuum of space, it can only leave by radiation. So wouldn't that require a very large array of radiators? Wouldn't that add a significant amount of mass to the spacecraft, affecting the overall mass efficiency?

As a secondary question: would the radiation pressure from "waste" heat for a nuclear powered electric engine be enough to make a worthwhile contribution to spacecraft thrust?

Comment: $\sigma T^4$ is your friend. Higher temperatures lead to much higher radiated heat from the same surface.

Comment: Visit [the site](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/realdesigns.php) with realistic (more or less) interplanetary spacecraft examples. Find some of the ones that use nuclear power - "Gasdynamic Mirror", francisdrakex's version of Hermes, HOPE/FFRE, Stuhlinger Ion Rocket - their common feature is ludicruous radiator area.

Comment: FFREs actually do not primarily extract fission energy as heat at all — that's their central selling point. Still, about 20% of their overall fission power must be radiated away as heat. (cc @SF.)

Comment: @DeerHunter Realistic, long-term working heat radiators can't have a temperature much bigger as around 2000K, which can be a serious limit if we are talking about the cooling of a realistic, long-term working nuclear reactor.

Comment: @peterh - agreed, and I'd say even working fluid temps greater than 600K are unhealthy (depending on the choice of alloy).

Comment: High-powered nuclear spacecraft tend to be nuclear thermal designs (i.e. they are used to heat propellant which is then expelled). Ion engines require on the order of 100 kW, which I wouldn't consider 'high-power' in this context. See the ISS for radiators that can reject 100 kW.

Answer (score 8):

As you stated, radiation is the only method of removing excess heat from a conventional spacecraft in vacuum. Designing a spacecraft to radiate heat appropriately is important and yes, it does add mass to the overall thermal control system. The best way to reduce that mass is to try and ensure the spacecraft doesn't *need* to radiate as much heat. For example, heat is desirable for maintaining electronics, propellant, or other components within required temperature ranges, so taking advantage of a nuclear source to provide that heat makes it an asset instead of waste (or at least some of it).

On the other hand, if you are talking about a [nuclear thermal rocket engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_thermal_rocket) then most of the heat generated by the nuclear source is ejected along with the exhaust. (See Deer Hunter's comments below.)

For your secondary question: using heat radiation pressure for thrust has definitely been considered (check out [nuclear photonic propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_photonic_rocket)). Also, that kind of effect has been observed as a perturbation on spacecraft already (see the [Pioneer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_anomaly)).

Comment: Not quite. Heat may be removed with the propellant - liquid hydrogen.

Comment: Do you mean with the exhaust? Or do you mean the liquid hydrogen is cold so it absorbs heat? The latter is simply moving the heat somewhere else -- which is another solution but does not _remove_ heat (similar to phase change materials).

Comment: The exhaust. Cooling becomes a problem after reactor shutdown - residual decay heat must be removed, and most designs I've read emphasize keeping LH2 flowing to cool the core even if specific impulse falls drastically.

Comment: Now I am more confused. What engine are you talking about? "Reactor" and "decay" suggest you are talking about an RTG power source, "keeping LH2 flowing to cool the core" sounds like a _closed_ system -- which, like I mentioned, cannot remove heat. Are you referring to the method of wrapping propellant lines around the engine nozzle for thermal control?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_Thermal_Rocket

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! The question seems to be referring to nuclear-to-electric for ion propulsion, but it is true that that type of rocket engine could be cooled by the exhaust (and he does say "_all_ nuclear propulsion concepts").

Comment: The question is about all nuclear-powered propulsion (NEP as well as NTR, and others), and it would be nice if your answer clarified what you mean by efficient design: "The best way to reduce that mass is to try and ensure the spacecraft doesn't need to radiate as much heat."

Comment: I said "all nuclear" because every description I've ever seen of a nuclear fueled system starts with the heat generated by either decay or fission. The core of my question pertains to high-power ion drives, where lots and lots of kWe are required, and that means lots of waste heat is produced by the powerplant.

Answer (score 5):

At higher power levels, the radiator comprises 70% of power plant mass.

Image Source
https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=fmIrAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=es-419#v=onepage&q&f=false

[image]

Comment: Is this figure 15 valid for power plants on Earth surface or for spacecrafts in the solar system?

Comment: The figure is from an article on nuclear reactors for space propulsion.You can check the link to the book to make sure.